# JavaScript object to handle drop-downs for date picker (three different dropdowns)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown

I am trying to get an object / array of DAY / MONTH / YEAR (in numbers) from 1900/01/01 for a Date of Birth selector.

Due to the designs, this needs to be selectable from 3 separate dropdown menus, DAY / MONTH / YEAR. The only way I have found where you can get an array of dates between two different days is the code below. I want to create an object, of DAYS / MONTH and YEARS between todays date (set automatically every day) and the year 1900.

```
// start and end date
var
  startDate = new Date("2017-10-01"),
  endDate = new Date("2017-10-07");

  // date array
var getDateArray = function(start, end) {

    var
      arr = new Array(),
      dt = new Date(start);

    while (dt <= end) {
      arr.push(new Date(dt));
      dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
    }

    return arr;

  }

  var startDate = new Date("1900-01-01"); //YYYY-MM-DD
var endDate = new Date("1900-01-07"); //YYYY-MM-DD

var getDateArray = function(start, end) {
    var arr = new Array();
    var dt = new Date(start);
    while (dt <= end) {
        arr.push(new Date(dt));
        dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

}